# Excel Formula, Trim parents of path to last child path name

Tags: microsoft-excel

say I have a path in A1: Stack/Over/Flow.

Is there a formula that can give me just 'Flow' in B1.

I know I can delimit but this gets tough when paths are of different lengths and when I just want the ending path.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the string.

This finds the last `/` and sets that as the starting point of the MID() function.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("{{{",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","{{{",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a look round and found this, which may help you.

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",A1)),A1,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))))`

Found at:
http://www.exceltactics.com/reverse-string-search-excel-using-find/2/

The formula listed here searches for the last word in a string using space, so to apply it to your paths I changed `" "` to `"/"` and and it seems to be working fine.  (I only tested a few strings so you may want to try several to be fully confident)

Comment: (1) It would be nice if you explained how this works. (2) This fails if the value in `A1` contains one or more tildes (``~``).  This might be an acceptable behavior, but you should definitely disclose it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you're going to use this, but I have to break path strings down quite a bit.

1) If you know you just want the last 4 characters on the right, you could use: `=right(A1,4)`.

2) If you want all components isolated, and they have different lengths, do     something like this:

```
In B1 enter =len(A1)           returns 15
In C1 enter =find("/",A1)      returns  6
In D1 enter =left(A1,C1-1)     returns stack
In E1 enter =right(A1,B1-C1)   returns over/flow
```

The cool thing about this is that if you copy these 4 cells to the right, it will break it down one more level.

```
Copy B1 to F1                  returns 9
Copy C1 to G1                  returns 5
Copy D1 to H1                  returns over
Copy E1 to I1                  returns flow
```

You can do this repeatedly. I routinely parse out 200+ character paths with a dozen or more subfolder levels.